# how to add conditional statement to Personal list?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, match-phrase

Currently I have this formula which combines cells values together and combines them to copy and paste into a document.

```
=IF(G2="","",J2&CHAR(10)&K2&CHAR(10)&L2&CHAR(10)&G2&" / "&H2&CHAR(10)&T2&"/ LOC NA "&O2&CHAR(10)&N2&" "&M2&CHAR(10)&"POST CONSTRUCTION BILLING REQUIRED / "&R2&" COUNTY")
```

I would like to add a function that says `if M2 = "200 AMPS"`, then add the phrase `"INSTALL 1/0 AL TPLX SERVICE"` to the output. I would like to add a variation of the bolded section.

```
=IF(G2="","",J2&CHAR(10)&K2&CHAR(10)&L2&CHAR(10)&G2&" / "&H2&CHAR(10)&T2&"/ LOC NA "&O2&CHAR(10)&N2&" "&M2&CHAR(10)&"POST CONSTRUCTION BILLING REQUIRED / "&R2&" COUNTY"&IF(M2="200 AMPS","INSTALL 1/0 AL TPLX SERVICE",""))
```

Comment: Add `& IF(M2="200 AMPS"," INSTALL 1/0 AL TPLX SERVICE","")` at the end of the concatenated text